# Is there a way to overlay a <canvas> over a fullscreen HTML5 <video>?

Tags: javascript, html, z-index, fullscreen, html5-video

I'm using videojs to play video, and I've done some manipulation on the video content frame by frame and display it in a `<canvas>` (ID: 'display').

When the video is playing, `<canvas>` can display in front of the `<video>` with the following css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    canvas#display {
        z-index: 1;
        postion: relative;
        top: some-video-height-px;
    }

    video#videoDiv_html5_api {
        z-index: -2;
    }

    div.vjs-controls {
        z-index: 3;
    }

</style>
```

It seems that `z-index` attribute is not working when `<video>` enters full screen mode.
It keeps in the front and `<canvas>` cannot overlay over `<video>`

---

> In W3C Documents
>   https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#ui

we have

```
:fullscreen {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:2147483647;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

It seems that z-index has been set to the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`...

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself. you just need to set the `canvas.style.z-index` to be 2147483647, then the  will cover

Comment: I'm curious which web browser you were using here. This solution should not work with Safari since full screen mode launches a native video playback client which hides the web browser and thus supersedes any and all elements within the browser regardless of z-index value.

Comment: Hmm... are you using the original webkitEnterFullscreen method of engaging full screen mode or the newer, "correct" webkitRequestFullScreen?

Comment: I'm using Chrome running on Windows. On mac, quicktime should be called according to my experience on iOS. I've no idea what version of method I'm using...