# HTML5 video: fullscreen subtitles

Tags: html, video, fullscreen, subtitle

Is it possible to show subtitles on an HTML5 video control in fullscreen mode?

I can show them (for example on FF 11.0) in window mode, with a slightly modified version of [cuepoint.js](http://cuepoint.org/) to show "live" subtitles:

```
Cuepoint.prototype.addLiveSlide = function(html) {
    var self;
    this.html = html;
    self = this;
    return this.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        return self.update(html);
    },
    false);
};
```

*But*, when user goes fullscreen, subtitles do not show... When back to window mode, they do show again.

Is this behaviour by design, a bug, or do I miss  something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firefox's native fullscreen-mode (using the fullscreen-api) hides everything but the element you requested fullscreen for regardless of z-index's.
the solution is quite easy though: wrap a container-div around the video and other content (such as the subtitles) and request fullscreen for that container instead.

the problem does not occur in chrome which respects z-index-values at any time

Comment: Latest windows verion of Chrome (18.0.1025.142 m) uses RP to play mp4 video with HTML5 (which doesn't even show the fullscreen button...). ogv video is not even played back...

Comment: And, sorry, I don't understand when you say "request fullscreen"... My code does not request fullscreen, the user is espected to ask for fullscreen clicking on the html5 toolbar fullscreen button, so I don't have any control on that...

Comment: hm, maybe there is a misunderstanding here: I assumed you added your own controls to the video - is that not the case? could you provide a more detailed code-example (e.g. in jsfiddle?)

Comment: Of course, sorry (was on Easter holiday... ;-), see http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/xHazS/ (hope it helps, I did a copy'n paste from page source, it's quite confused... :-()

Comment: that's way too messy to look thru :( for the sake of getting somewhere I suggest you look into good html5 players such as http://mediaelementjs.com/ - it uses custom controls and thereby provides advanced control over whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

could you do some magic involving Video and Canvas?
http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: Hi! I did make a test using an approach similar to that of html5doctor (only using canvas over video instead of reverse), but no success with fullscreen. This issue seems addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461453/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-a-canvas-over-a-fullscreen-html5-video, but I had no success even usinz z-index:Integer.MAX_VALUE...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying [playr](https://github.com/delphiki/Playr) which supports full screen (apparently - I've not actually tested that part of it myself).

Comment: Hi! I did test playr, and they do fullscreen captions. Though, they use SubRip/WebVTT tracks, which I suppose are not well fitted for *live* injection. But I could be wrong...

Comment: I've not tried that although I don't see why they wouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome works out of the box

- http://fguillen.github.com/ChromeVideoSubsStyle/