# Displaying elements other than fullscreen element (HTML5 fullscreen API)

Tags: html, css, z-index, fullscreen

When I "fullscreen" an element (let's say a div), I can't get anything other elements to appear (while in fullscreen mode). Why is that happening? How can I accomplish this?

Related: [Is there a way to overlay a <canvas> over a fullscreen HTML5 <video>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461453/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-a-canvas-over-a-fullscreen-html5-video)

Comment: Potentially relevant browser spec addition: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/what-is-the-top-layer/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems that browsers (Chrome 28, Firefox 23) set the `z-index` of fullscreened elements to 2147483647 (the largest 32-bit signed number). According to tests, setting the `z-index` of other elements to the same `z-index` will cause them to show, but the `z-index` of the fullscreened element can not be changed (it can, but the browser just ignores the value — even with !important).

Maybe the only reference I could find to this:

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/fullscreen/full-screen-zIndex.html

Also, in Chrome dev tools:

[image: Computed style on fullscreened element]

So either set elements to the maximum `z-index`, or, the better solution would be to just create a container element, make it so that all elements you want to display are children of the container element, and fullscreen it.

Comment: When I tried this, it only worked in Chrome, not Firefox or IE11, though the z-index of the fullscreened element was set in all three.

Comment: same here, 3 years later.

Comment: Here's the Firefox solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798213/firefox-fullscreen-video-append-dom-elements

Comment: After Chrome's update to v.69 this solution (which was also implemented by myself) won't work anymore, so a better one that seems to work fine is the Firefox one provided by Dalibor.