# OpenLayers 3 - fullscreen control - Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-ui, firefox, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 (3.13.0) and jQuery UI (1.11.4).

All the jQuery components (dialog box, tooltip, autocomplete) do not work in Chrome and Firefox, in fullscreen mod, initiated using the OpenLayers fullscreen control.

And then I followed this example: [Displaying elements other than fullscreen element (HTML5 fullscreen API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578244/displaying-elements-other-than-fullscreen-element-html5-fullscreen-api)

This solution actually worked on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

Also I noticed that, going into fullscreen mode, using the fullscreen of Firefox itself doesn't cause any issues, so I assume it is related to OpenLayers control. Do you have any idea why?

EDIT:

Can you also tell me how to do it?

```
new ol.control.FullScreen({
  source: document.getElementById('map'),                    
          document.getElementsByClassName("ui-autocomplete"), 
          document.getElementsByClassName("ui-dialog"), 
          document.getElementsByClassName("ui-tooltip")
})
```

did not work.

I am trying to add the classes, because the div's where these functionalities are used are already inside the map div.

EDIT 2:

Ok, I noticed that classes are not added to the map div, so I gave an id to the body, and used that inside source, and it worked!

```
new ol.control.FullScreen({
  source: document.querySelector("#body")
})
```

Comment: is this happening with the latest version 3.14.0???. Within the release page they state this imporvement. `New source option for the ol.control.FullScreen, to allow including other elements besides the map in a full screen view (#4679).`. check it here https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.14.0

Comment: I updated to 3.14.0, but the problem still persists. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You'll have to make use of the new `source` option to include not just the map viewport, but also your other ui elements in the fullscreen view.

Comment: At the end, your suggestion worked, I just needed to define the source in a correct way. So, If you reply, I can accept your answer.