# Make a div visible on full screen of another div

Tags: javascript, html

I made an element take full screen by using the below method:

```js
if (element.requestFullscreen) {
  element.requestFullscreen();
} else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
  element.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else {
  return;
}
```

It works well but I want to show another element when on the fullscreen mode.

The other element has `position: fixed` and `z-index: 999999999` but it's not visible when on fullscreen mode.

Could anyone help me, please?

**Below is the link to the example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-z1phjd?file=index.html

So I want to show the blue element when the red element is full screen sized.

Comment: does z-index help!

Comment: I have tried `z-index` but it didnt work.

Comment: could you add your html and css you've tried?

Comment: I will add stackblitz example

Comment: Can you try overlapping the elements? - https://jsfiddle.net/s1b2eokh/4/

Comment: Also, I'm unable to load the example you attached. The webpage stuck on loading for 3 minutes or so.

Comment: try to exit the current element full-screen mode and make the other fullscreen.

Comment: The stackblitz url has been updated

Comment: @lftieaq, Another div should be outside of the target element.

Comment: Try adding `.fullscreen-element {  opacity: 0.5;  }  :fullscreen:not(:root)::backdrop {  background: #00FF00;  opacity: 0.5;  }` to your css. Also, see the specification: https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/ "This specification introduces a new stacking layer … It is called the top layer, … and is therefore rendered closest to the user within a viewport. Each document has one associated viewport and therefore also one top layer."

Comment: Also you can (temporarily) hide the fullscreen content and its backdrop `.fullscreen-element {  pointer-events: none;  visibility: hidden;  opacity: 0;  }
:fullscreen:not(:root)::backdrop {  display: none;  }`

Comment: Hmm i dont think it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it was once possible to solve this issue with z-index but its since been patched by newer browser releases - [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578244/displaying-elements-other-than-fullscreen-element-html5-fullscreen-api)

I believe [Tushar Vaghela's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385267/tushar-vaghela) answer is your best chance of achieving your desired result, which is to include the elements you wish to overlay within the fullscreened element - [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798213/firefox-fullscreen-video-append-dom-elements).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a div surrounding all the fullscreen elements will work and then you can position the elements inside as you wish. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/840urcsf/6/

The snippet doesn't enable the fullscreen, but here it goes:

```js
(() => {
  const btn = document.querySelector(".make-fullscreen");

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const element = document.querySelector(".fullscreen-container");
    console.log(element);
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.fullscreen-element {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.other-element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullscreen-container">
      <div class="fullscreen-element">
          <button class="make-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
      </div>
    <div class="other-element">
          other element
      </div>
      </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/alan_omar/vp6h8enL/11/),
You can do it through dom manipulation by listening to `fullscreenchange` event and following these steps:

1-add the `other-element` element as child of `fullscreen-element` in full screen mode.

2-bring `other-element` back to its original location in the normal mode.

```
(() => {
  const btn = document.querySelector(".make-fullscreen");
  const element = document.querySelector(".fullscreen-element");
  const other = document.querySelector(".other-element");

  element.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", event => {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
      element.appendChild(other);
    } else {
      element.parentNode.insertBefore(other,element.nextSibling)
    }
  });

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Is it not possible while keeping the other-element's location?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You are moving the other-element inside the fullscreen-element when it's on full screen? I want to not move the element

Comment: I guess you can clone the `other-element` node and insert it in `full-element` in fullscreen mode,and delete it in normal mode.

Comment: @yash i updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alan_omar/vp6h8enL/21/) to use the clone approach

Answer (score 0):

The full screen works here: https://jsfiddle.net/trentHarlem/7861L0ph/

```js
(() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('.fullscreen-element');
  const other = document.querySelector('.other-element');
  const btn = document.querySelector('.make-fullscreen');

  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    

      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.fullscreen-element {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.other-element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 24px;
  z-index: 999999999999;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="fullscreen-element">
      <button class="make-fullscreen">TOGGLE Fullscreen</button>
      <div class="other-element">other element</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, it's nothing different from mine. It looks like it just toggles the visibility of the blue element. I need the blue element to be shown on the full screen.

Comment: Would you Please clarify which elements blue /red that you want to see on full screen and not full screen. I can already see both so i assumed you wanted a toggle

Comment: i updated my attempt but I'm still not certain what you are looking for.  I do notice that the full screen functionality doesn't always work properly from code editors. so i'm using vs code. JS fiddle seems less quirky so i included a link

Answer (score 0):

how about simply move "other-element" to inside "fullscreen-element"? And change "fullscreen-element" position to relative.

```js
(() => {
  const btn = document.querySelector(".make-fullscreen");

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const element = document.querySelector(".fullscreen-element");
    console.log(element);
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.fullscreen-element {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
}

.other-element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 24px;
  z-index: 999999999999;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fullscreen-element">
        <button class="make-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>

        <div class="other-element">
        other element
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```